# Stream h264 raw data using appsrc

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, rtp

I got a raw h264 video (I knew it was the exact same format I need) and developed an application that plays it.

Can someone suggest me how to take raw h264 video data using appsrc and stream the data using rtp.?

-
Praveen

Answer (score 0):

Your pipeline  will look something like this:

```
appsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink
```